# estimate_means omits one of my groups in R (modelbased, Estimated Marginal Means)

Tags: r, emmeans

I'm trying to calculate estimated marginal means for a score ("realscore") for a group number of children in 4 different schools who have spent different amounts of time in school:

```
ChildTIS ChildSex   realscore   SchoolCode
8.02        2               7           B
11.04       1               6           C

#EMMS for school by child time in school - reality
realmodel <- lm(realscore ~ SchoolCode * ChildTIS * ChildSex, data = gcsubsetdata)
means_complex_real <- estimate_means(realmodel,at = "SchoolCode")
means_complex_real

SchoolCode | Mean |   SE |       95% CI
---------------------------------------
A          | 0.94 | 0.20 | [0.53, 1.35]
B          | 0.68 | 0.29 | [0.10, 1.25]
C          |      |      |             
D          | 1.79 | 0.29 | [1.22, 2.37]
```

There are four schools coded A, B, C and D and as you can see above the EMMs table omits one of the schools.

I originally coded the schools 1, 2, 3 and 4 because that was the order we tested them in. I can use estimate_means for the numerical code but it gives different means. This is not a true numeric variable though so I wanted to check my results using the categorical variable.

```
realmodel <- lm(realscore ~ SchoolID * ChildTIS * ChildSex, data = gcsubsetdata)
means_complex_real <- estimate_means(realmodel,at = list(SchoolID = c(1,2,3,4)))
means_complex_real
SchoolID | Mean |   SE |       95% CI
-------------------------------------
1.00     | 0.83 | 0.19 | [0.45, 1.20]
2.00     | 1.10 | 0.13 | [0.84, 1.37]
3.00     | 1.38 | 0.16 | [1.06, 1.70]
4.00     | 1.66 | 0.24 | [1.17, 2.15]
```

If I specify the school codes to use it still omits school C:

```
realmodel <- lm(realscore ~ SchoolCode * ChildTIS * ChildSex, data = gcsubsetdata)
means_complex_real <- estimate_means(realmodel,at = list(SchoolCode = c("A","B","C","D")))
means_complex_real
SchoolCode | Mean |   SE |       95% CI
---------------------------------------
A          | 0.94 | 0.20 | [0.53, 1.35]
B          | 0.68 | 0.29 | [0.10, 1.25]
C          |      |      |             
D          | 1.79 | 0.29 | [1.22, 2.37]
```

If I subset the data it STILL omits school C:

```
gcsubset2 <- subset(gcsubsetdata, SchoolCode=="C" | SchoolCode == "D")


realmodel <- lm(realscore ~ SchoolCode * ChildTIS * ChildSex, data = gcsubset2)
means_complex_real <- estimate_means(realmodel,at = "SchoolCode")
means_complex_real


SchoolCode | Mean |   SE |       95% CI
---------------------------------------
C          |      |      |             
D          | 1.78 | 0.34 | [1.05, 2.50]
```

There is no missing data for any of the variables realscore, SchoolCode, ChildTIS or ChildSex in the dataframe. It will calculate unadjusted means just fine.

Answers to questions:
School C has 10 data points.

I still get the following if I rename them as SchA etc.

```
SchoolCode | Mean |   SE |       95% CI
```

---

SchA       | 0.94 | 0.20 | [0.53, 1.35]
SchB       | 0.68 | 0.29 | [0.10, 1.25]
SchC       |      |      |
SchD       | 1.79 | 0.29 | [1.22, 2.37]

The results of realmodel:

```
Call:
```

lm(formula = realscore ~ SchoolCode * ChildTIS * ChildSex, data = gcsubsetdata)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)                    SchoolCodeSchB
3.26627                          -3.19701
SchoolCodeSchC                    SchoolCodeSchD
-0.54741                           2.73317
ChildTIS                          ChildSex
-0.22716                          -0.95491
SchoolCodeSchB:ChildTIS           SchoolCodeSchC:ChildTIS
0.19012                                NA
SchoolCodeSchD:ChildTIS           SchoolCodeSchB:ChildSex
-0.16173                           1.42028
SchoolCodeSchC:ChildSex           SchoolCodeSchD:ChildSex
0.77606                          -1.66379
ChildTIS:ChildSex  SchoolCodeSchB:ChildTIS:ChildSex
0.09136                          -0.07284
SchoolCodeSchC:ChildTIS:ChildSex  SchoolCodeSchD:ChildTIS:ChildSex
NA                           0.14938

Simpler model

```
#EMMS for school by child time in school - reality
realmodel <- lm(realscore ~ SchoolCode + ChildTIS + ChildSex, data = gcsubsetdata)

means_complex_real <- estimate_means(realmodel,at = "SchoolCode")

means_complex_real
```

Now works

```
Estimated Marginal Means

SchoolCode | Mean |   SE |       95% CI
---------------------------------------
A          | 0.96 | 0.19 | [0.58, 1.34]
B          | 0.69 | 0.25 | [0.19, 1.19]
C          | 1.62 | 0.29 | [1.04, 2.20]
D          | 1.79 | 0.27 | [1.24, 2.34]
```

Comment: A couple of things to try - does it still happen if you make the schools "sch_A", "sc_B", "sc_C" etc.. - just in case `"C"` is getting passed as `c` at some point under the hood.  Also, how many data points does school C have?

Comment: Can you add the results of `summary(realmodel)` to your answer?

Comment: Comments answered above in edits, thanks

Comment: SOLVED - it turns out that I hadn't spotted that school C has a constant ChildTIS.

A simpler model works and is now added to the above.

Comment: I have no idea what package has a function named `estimate_means`, but it is not in the **emmeans** package.

Comment: Apologies, it's in **modelbased**. I don't know if I can edit the title but I'll try.